# There a way to perform a booking-like payment with paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

I must replicate the payment method that booking.com made sometimes:

Step 1 - i insert my credit card number as warranty (there's no real payment at this point.My data is stored somewhere).
Step 2a - If i cancel my reservation a percentual amount (like 20%) of my reservation price will be taken from my credit card
Step 2b - I go to the hotel and i conclude correctly my reservation (100% of my reservation price will be taken from my credit card. The hotel can do this automatically with the data of my web reservation or maybe the hotel can take physically my credit card number).

I have to use paypal or something similar (like BancaSella). This payment method has an "official" name in their api ? If this method not exist in their api how can achive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Authorization and Capture](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/intro/), and possibly the use of [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/intro/#reference-transactions).